# Xamarin.Forms (WinPhone) Hide the Title space NavigationBar for Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage. Please

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

In App.cs, when I set the `Main page = new MyContentPage()`. It is doing good. However, I have to do `Navigation.PushAsync(somePage())`, so when I changed `Main page = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage())` it comes out with a huge title space, which I don't want that. Please help me to hide that. Thanks.

UPDATE:
I've tried `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)`  is not working to me. Can I know which version of Xamarin.Forms is working for `SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)` ? I've tried both Xamarin.Forms 2.0 and the latest 2.3 and they are both seem not responsive to WinPhone.
Is there anyway I can modified it in WinPhone Independent API?

My code:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new CP());
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the title bar of your `NavigationPage` by calling: `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Comment: where should I call that actually?

Answer (score 1):

OK, Solved. Sorry for my weak understanding.

Should be:

```
    public class CP : ContentPage
    {
        public CP()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            //....
        }
    }
```